# Is it possible to display the spoken text using cordova-plugin-speechrecognition

Tags: cordova, speech-recognition

I am looking for a way to display the text that was spoken using speech reccognition. I have used  cordova-plugin-speechrecognition .
I could tap on the mic and speack using startListening function. But is there any way to display the spoken text on screen.
Reference : https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/401/how-to-use-the-speech-recognition-api-in-cordova

Answer (score 0):

you can put the text in an html text tag, in my example the id sstBtn

```
function startRecognition(){
    return window.speechRecognition.startRecognition({
        language:"en-US",
        showPopup: true
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log("Results",data);
        var sttElement = parentElement.querySelector('.stt');
        sttElement.innerHTML = data[0]
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have displayed the result instantly after recognizing
**page.ts**

```
constructor(private speech:SpeechRecognition,private cd:ChangeDetectorRef) {

   this.speech.startListening(
      {
        language:"en-US",
        matches:1
      }
    ).subscribe((matches)=>{
          this.matches=matches;
          this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Use `ChangeDetectorRef` to update change

Now in **page.html**

```
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
   {{matches}}
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Efficient method to display the text with the help of ngzone
    Include private speech:SpeechRecognition and private ngzone;NgZone in constructor 
**page.ts**
 
    '''
       this.speech.startListening(
          {
            language:"en-US",
            matches:1
          }
        ).subscribe((matches)=>{
          this.ngzone.run( ()=> {
              this.matches=matches;
    });
    });
    '''
    **page.html**
    '''
    <ion-card>
      <ion-card-content>
       {{matches}}
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
'''
```